# result hits in multiple columns using Algolia and Bootstrap 3

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, algolia

I'm using Algolia instantsearch.js for search, and to display my result page, I'm using Bootstrap 3, and I'd like hits to be displayed in 3 columns:

```
qry | hit1 | hit2
    | hit3 | hit4
    | hit5 | hit6
```

(where qry = the search query input widget)
etc..

If it's mobile, it should display as:

```
qry
hit1
hit2
hit3
etc.
```

Can someone help me with the html/css I can use to implement this?
Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Basically, you want to use bootstrap `row`s and grid layout `col-{xs,sm,md,lg}-X` (More info about the grid layout [here](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid)).
One interesting property with `bootstrap` is that if you declare a block as being `col-YY-X`, if the screen width is under the dimensions YY is associated with, it automatically expands to the full width.
[`instantsearch.js`](https://community.algolia.com/instantsearch.js/)'s widgets expose a `cssClasses` parameter that allows you to customize the classes of the underlying markup.

To easily do two columns, all you need to do is declare the `root` element of the `cssClasses` as being a `.row`, and each result as a `.col-sm-6` (or `.col-md-6` or `.col-lg-6` depending on which screen size you want it to apply).

By combining them, you can have some really interesting layouts.
[See this JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dfve48te/6/)

Here, I've extended a bit the idea. Try to resize the view, and you'll see that it automatically picks a number of results to display per line depending on the width by combining multiple `col-YY-X` classes on the hit widget.

```js
search.addWidget(
  instantsearch.widgets.hits({
    container: '#hits',
    templates: {
      empty: 'No results',
      item: '<div class="hit">{{title}}</div>'
    },
    hitsPerPage: 6,
    cssClasses: {
      root: 'row',
      item: 'col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6'
    }
  })
);
```

As you can see, I've also added an inner class to the `item` template to be able to use the item as a wrapper with `padding` inside to avoid having the hits glued to each other. I apply the `border` to the inner element, because adding `margin`s to bootstrap grid elements is not the right solution.

The layout itself is really simple, you can just nest rows together:

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div id="search" class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <div id="input"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-8">
      <div id="hits" class="row">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```