# Displaying a 'Top Result' with Algolia?

Tags: algolia

I want to search 3 different indices at once, breaking out their results into 3 separate sections.

Above these 3 sections though, I want to display a 4th section with a single result row, and this section will be titled "Best Result".

It should take the best result of the 3 indices that most perfectly matches.

Does anyone know how I can achieve this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By design, when the ranking of each index is properly set (both attributeToIndex, and customRanking settings filled), the Algolia engine returns the most relevant et popular results for each new search request. First the one without typos and with perfect matches, then the others...

Which mean that if you want to display all the top results on a single page, you only need to take the N first result of each index. 
Then it's just a matter of display. Like on the following websites, you can imagine to display those results into multiple columns:

- [http://telly.com/](http://telly.com/search/breaking)
- [Prototype built using the TED API](https://demos.algolia.com/ted/#query=body)

*Feel free to look at tips about the best way to display [result hits in multiple columns using Algolia and Bootstrap 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34433830/result-hits-in-multiple-columns-using-algolia-and-bootstrap-3/34435266#34435266)*

Beside that you can also consider passing the getRankingInfo=1 parameter with your search query, and filter the results displayed accordingly to the matching info returned for each hit within the `_rankingInfo` property.

```
firstMatchedWord: 2000
geoDistance: 0
geoPrecision: 1
nbExactWords: 2
nbTypos: 0
proximityDistance: 1
userScore: 9499
words: 2
```

Comment: I understand I can break out the results of the 3 indices in 3 sections (i.e. top 5 for index A, B, C). But I want to have a 4th section which chooses ONE from all indexes and labels it as "best match", and that should go at the very top... so it may very well come from any index. I think you answered it by the second part of your question which says I can get the ranking 'score' and determine the ultimate best match. Right?

Comment: For `getRankingInfo`, do I just sort by `userScore`?

Comment: Ok I had a look, it looks like userscore is what I want but I can't find it documented anywhere. Is that the overall 'confidence score' of a search result? If so, this is perfect

Comment: Here the `userScore` is per index, so that won't work. Maybe then, what you could do
1/ is pushing all the record to a single index with an extra attribut on each record that describes the `type`
2/Then at query time, add for 3 of your requests, a facetFilter to only retrieve records from each type. And no filter for the 4th section. 
In that case you would retrieve the best results whatever the type of each record.

Note: you need then to have an homogenous customRanking value for your 3 type of records. The custom ranking could be 
- common customRanking value
- numericValue index 1

Comment: The custom ranking could be 1/ common numericValue value 2/ numericValue first index 3/ numericValue second index 4/ numericValue third index